# multi-part form post with binary data on Android 4.0 using HTML5 and Angular

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, post, multipart

First, let's just be clear: there is no form, there is not file input. The image files I need to upload is obtained via the cordova camera API. No user file picking of any kind. I mention this explicitly because most of these sort of questions involve the user utilizing a form with a file input element and picking a file. This is NOT what I need to do.

Secondly tech in use is:

- Android 4.0
- Angular 1.3.x
- Cordova

In other words, a hybrid HTML5 application on Android 4.0

I have code working on android 4.3 - no problems.
Unfortunately, the `Blob` constructor is not supported on 4.0, which is the start of my problems.

Using the deprecated `BlobBuilder` API (which IS available on 4.0), I seem to be able to get a Blob constructed.
BUT, the binary image data just does not make it into the request to the server (I have created a dummy receiver Servlet, that just simply dumps the received POST body to console - all other fields are present, but the `file` field has no binary content).

Blob creation code:

```
    try {
          imgBlob = new Blob ([data],{type:'image/' + imageExt});
        }
        catch (e) {
          $log.info('Apparently Blob constructor not supported, attempting fallback to BlobBuilder API');
          window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                     window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                     window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                     window.MSBlobBuilder;

          $log.debug('Selected BlobBuilder: ' + window.BlobBuilder);

         if(e.name === 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder){
           $log.debug ('We got exception TypeError');
           var bb = new BlobBuilder();
           bb.append(data);
           imgBlob = bb.getBlob('image/' + imageExt);

         }
         else if(e.name === 'InvalidStateError'){
           $log.debug ('We got exception InvalidStateError');
           // InvalidStateError (tested on FF13 WinXP)
           imgBlob = new Blob( data.buffer, {type : 'image/'+imageExt});
         }
         else{
           $log.error ('We\'re screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely');
         }
        }
```

The `data` paramaters is an ArrayBuffer object. As far as I can tell, it DOES contain the correct image data.

The actual upload code:

```
     var uploadUrl ='https://uploadReceiverUrl' ,
        requestData =  {
                file: {val:imgBlob,contentDisposition:imgMetaData.uuid + '.' + imageExt},
                imageid: imgMetaData.uuid,
                formId: imgMetaData.formId,
                key: theKey,
                hmac: hmac,
                userId: imgMetaData.userId
        },
        headers = {
            'Content-Type':undefined
        };

        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : uploadUrl,
            headers : headers,
            data:requestData,
            transformRequest: FormDataObject
        })
        .success (function (data,status) {

            //Handle success by deleting image - this is fine.
        })
        .error (function (data, status) {
            $log.warn ('UploadService.uploadImage():: failed. Status ' + status + ', data: ' + data);              
        });
```

The mentioned `transformRequest` function is very simple. Essentially:

```
  function (data) {
    var fd = new FormData();

    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {


    if ( typeof value === 'object' ) {

        fd.append(key, value.val, value.contentDisposition);

    }

    else {
        fd.append(key, value);
        $log.debug ('FormDataObject:: Added to FormData (' + key + ') with val (' + value + ')' );
    }
}}
```

SO I am either missing something very stupid or small, OR there is some crucial support not available in Android 4.0 that I have so far failed to discover.

Halp?

Comment: So you are able to create a binary blob data of your image in android 4.0 using the BlobBuilder you injected in the webview but that data you arent able to send it through your POST request to the server. Am i correct?

Comment: @Kushal in essence, yes. The POST request reaches the server, but the binary content of the images is simply not in the multi-part body (the other fields are present).

Comment: So did you check that when you append your blob data in your FormData object here if ( typeof value === 'object' ) {

        fd.append(key, value.val, value.contentDisposition);

    } whether its present in it?

Comment: @Kushal - yes, as far as I could tell, it is. Some more information (and a kludgy work-a-round): I have now resorted to using `FileReader` to read the `Blob`. In the `onloadend` event, I can then actually obtain the Base64 encoded data URL (string), and append that to the FormData. This works (verified against test service), BUT means larger uploads, and non-trivial changes on real service side. So...less than ideal.